# Changing the label on a edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

So i have implemented a timer that calls a timertask extension called labelsTimer. The method should change the label of the text to that stipulated in the code but instead throws a error

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

this is the code

```
public class labelsTimer extends TimerTask {
EditText label;

labelsTimer(EditText label)
{   super();
    this.label = label;
}
@Override
public void run()
{

    System.out.print("fsdfsd");
    label.setText("hehehehe");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
public void run(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        label.setText("hehehehe");
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: When i do that i get a red line under "runOnUiThread" forcing my to create a "runOnUiThread" method

Comment: Honour this member ^^

Answer (score 0):

change the label in this wrapper thread

```
try {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
             label.setText("hehehehe");
         }
    });          
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Same as above, When i do it, i get a red line under "runOnUiThread" forcing my to create a "runOnUiThread" method